# Search by text through the attached sources in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-13

Is it possible to search through the attached sources in IntelliJIDEA 13?
If it is, how to enable that feature?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem:

In the search dialog (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) click on custom scope and click on ellipsis button.

Then use the following pattern:

```
lib:*.*
```

All the sources will be included in your search.

Answer (score 2):

Hitting the shift key twice should bring up the "search everywhere" dialog.

This reference is for version 14, but I believe it is still valid for version 13.
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/searching-everywhere.html

Comment: This way I can only search for a file, but is it possible to search by text? Hitting ctrl + shift + F opens a search dialog - but it doesn't include files attached as sources.